# Си. Проблема с записью данных из файла в связанный кольцевой список

Tags: c++, c, односвязный-список

Всем привет! Изучаю си, и появилась задача из файла считать имена и записать их в кольцевой список. Имена читаются, но в список записывается последнее.
Вот код:

````
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define L 11 

struct node
{
    char* info;
    struct node* next;
};
void prnlist(struct node* t)
{
    if (t == NULL) //пустой список
        return;
    struct node* p = t->next;
    while (p != t)
    {
        printf("%s ", p->info);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("%s ", p->info);
    printf("\n");
}
struct node* first(char* val)
{
    struct node* p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->next = p;
    p->info = val;
    return p;
}



struct node* addtail(struct node* t, char* val)
{
    struct node* p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->next = t->next;
    t->next = p;
    p->info = val;
    return p;
}

struct node* read(const char* name)
{
    FILE* fp;
    struct node* t = NULL;
    char buf[L], * temp;
    if ((fp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL)
        return 0;
    if ((temp = fgets(buf, L - 1, fp)) != NULL)
        t = first(buf);

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        if ((temp = fgets(buf, L - 1, fp)) == NULL)
            break;
        t = addtail(t, buf);
        //prnlist(t);
    }
    prnlist(t);

    fclose(fp);
    return t;
}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    struct node* names = read("Names.txt");
    //prnlist(names);
}```

В файле names.txt
````

Ашот
Иван
Максим
Алексей
Александр

```
Но prnlist выводит только Александр Александр Александр Александр Александр
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте в `addtail(t, strdup(buf))` (и в `first()` тоже).

Сейчас вы запоминаете адрес одной и той же памяти (в которую читаете файл) во всех элементах списка.

Кстати, `addtail()` можно чуть скорректировать и `first()` будет не нужен. Т.е. можно передать туда NULL (когда списка еще нет) и в зависимости от этого устанавливать `next` либо на начало списка, либо на только что созданный элемент (для первого в списке).

```
struct node* addtail(struct node* t, char* val)
{
    struct node* p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (t) {
        p->next = t->next;
        t->next = p;
    } else
        p->next = p;

    p->info = val;
    return p;
}
```

При таком подходе `read()` (только ее надо обязательно переименовать) упроститься:

```
struct node* read_list (const char* name)
{
    FILE* fp;
    struct node* t = NULL;
    char buf[L];
    if ((fp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL)
        return 0;
    
    while (fgets(buf, L - 1, fp))
        t = addtail(t, strdup(buf));

    prnlist(t);

    fclose(fp);
    return t;
}
```

Еще один момент. Ваш вариант `prnlist()` можно тоже сократить, например, так:

```
void prnlist (struct node* t)
{
    if (t == NULL) {
       struct node* p = t;
       do {
          printf("%s ", p->info);
          p = p->next;
       } while (p != t);
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```